# What do should I do to make AC_FL_RUNContent to play remote swf?

Tags: actionscript, adobe, flash

Suppose on windows if I map the Z:/ drive to some folder on the network and my swf resides there. Can I embed that swf in the html using AC_FL_RUNContent and specifing the path as Z:/test.swf??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using 'file:///Z:/test.swf' ?

Comment: This didnt work. Actually the server would look for Z:// drive. But once the client receives the html response i want the client to get the file from the Z:/

Comment: hmmm. I'm slightly confused...what do you mean by 'get the file' ? Do you want the client to view the page from Z:// with the swf embedded or do you want the client to download the swf to his machine ?

Comment: Ok its like this. THe user is not supposed to access the coursefiles which is in swf from Z://. Instead of that, he is given LMS access, I dont want teh course to be stored on LMS, becoz the it eats up lot of bandwith of the network b/w client and the LMS server, so instead I just want the server to send the html response back to client with just the file name and the file has to be picked by the client from the Z:// and start streaming it. Is it possible??